# How can a terraform module return different values based on a parameter(variable) passed on from the caller

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform module like so:

```
variable "whitelist_map" {
  type    = "map"
  default = {
    "10.1.1.1/32" = "alb_external_facing"
    "10.2.2.2"    = "jenkins_lb"
  }
}

output "whitelist_map" {
  value = "${var.whitelist_map}"
}
```

However, I would like `whitelist_map` to return one of two possible values based on a variable (let's say `callervar`). If the `callervar` has a value of 1 , then one value gets returned. If `callervar` has a value of 2, then another value gets returned.

Value of `callervar` will come down from the caller Terraform code

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is a `List` because `Map` does not provide an array like structure instead it gives you key-value-like store.

Like you said, this code needs to have an `index` to access to the `List` item. The `index` variable is named as `foo` and is `number` type. The rest is done by `list(map(string))` which provides you `Map` of `List`s in `string` type.

In the last snippet, you access to that variable with index we provided earlier.

```
variable "foo" {
  type = number
}

variable "whitelist_list" {
  type    = list(map(string))
  default = [
    { "10.1.1.1/32" = "alb_external_facing" },
    { "10.2.2.2"    = "jenkins_lb" }
  ]
}

output "whitelist" {
  value = var.whitelist_list[var.foo]
}
```